# Cookie character encoding in IE/Firefox

Tags: cookies, encoding, character-encoding, cross-browser

I am adding a cookie in my ajax response. The cookie contains some unicode characters (e.g. `تست`).
However when I want to show the cookie content to the user in Firefox and IE, it displays `ØªØ³Øª`).
Is there anything I can do to be able to get the correct characters in Firefox and IE?

Answer (score -2):

Save in cookie some id, and extract data by this id (from array, database, files)